# Broadcast Receiver MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED never called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, auto-update

I have the following app scenario:
1) an app which updates by itself
2) the device is rooted
3) the checks for the version online and if new version is online it downloads the 'apk' file and installs it

Everything works fine but the APP does not restart after the new version install. I tried to set the MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED Broadcast Receiver, but it is never called. The app install new and stops but the receiver in the app is never triggered.

What am I doing wrong?

The code:
MANIFEST

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.OnUpgradeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
              <data android:scheme="package"/>
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I tried the receiver manifest code with the DATA part and without ... and it still does not work!!

BROADCAST RECEIVER CLASS

```
public class OnUpgradeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String msg="intent:"+intent+" action:"+intent.getAction();
        Log.e("OLE","RECEIVEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEED: "+msg);
    }}
```

APP UPDATE PART

```
Process p;  
                    try {  

                        //Runtime.getRuntime().exec (new String[]{"su", "-c", "pm install -r " + apkLocation +  "party.net"});

                            // Preform su to get root privledges  
                            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");   

                            // Attempt to write a file to a root-only  
                            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());  
                            os.writeBytes("/system/bin/pm install -r"+apkLocation+"\n");  

                            // Close the terminal  
                            os.writeBytes("exit\n");  
                            os.flush();  
                            try {  
                                    p.waitFor();
                                    if (p.exitValue() != 255) {  
                                            Log.e("OLE","Sucess :-)");
                                    }  
                                    else {  
                                        Log.e("OLE","Fail 1");
                                    }  

                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                                Log.e("OLE","Fail 2");
                            }  
                    } catch (IOException e) {  
                        Log.e("OLE","Fail 3 "+e.getMessage());
                    }
```

**SOLVED!** 
The problem was that the new VERSION which was installed above the previous one did not have the broadcast receiver set!!!

Comment: SOLVED! The problem was that the new VERSION which was installed above the previous one did not have the broadcast receiver set!!!

Comment: I can't get it to work - what android version are you using it on?

Comment: Mine isn't working either and now from android O onwards we can't use the PACKAGE_REPLACED INTENT

Comment: Ok, the same problem could be find on some asus devices, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44415369/6548766)

Comment: FYI, android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED was deprecated and replaced by android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED
(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED)

Also it appears that you don't need <data android:scheme="package"/> in the manifest receiver declaration anymore. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27756663/3314615)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to receive intent for new app if the new one is not running, the best solution is to use another app-B to receive intent and run the new app-A.